# How to register an existing bean in Application context and what is the advantage I get out of it?

Tags: java, spring

I am a newbie to Spring. I was going through spring documentation where it says we can register existing objects created outside spring container in application context. I did that like this

```
OutsideBean outsideBean = new OutsideBean();
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
// SpringBean is the bean which is defined in spring.xml
SpringBean springBean = applicationContext.getBean("springBean", SpringBean.class); 
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory =
    applicationContext.getBeanFactory();
configurableListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton("outsideBean", outsideBean);
```

I have many unanswered questions here.

1. The way I am doing above, is it correct.?
2. Even if it is correct, is it the best way to do that.?
3. What if I have to register a bean as a 'prototype'.?
4. By registering my bean in application context what is the advantage I get out of it.?

I read through many links in stackoverflow but couldnt understand it. Hence asking it in new thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. AFAIK, yes
2. No, it's not the best way. The best way is to create the context from a Spring configuration class, and to create beans in this configuration class, using @Bean annotated methods, as described [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java). Or simply by annotating your class with @Component and letting Spring find your bean by classpath scanning.
3. Your specify a scope [using the @Scope annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-specifying-bean-scope)
4. The advantage is that the bean is managed by Spring, and can thus be injected by Spring in all the other beans. It can also be injected by any other bean. And it can benefit from AOP in order, for example, to provide transactional methods.

Comment: Yes I read about Component and Bean annotations. I can declare all my bean like that and let spring take care of it. But what I am asking here is, in what scenarios do I have to explicitly register beans in application context.? Assuming there is a case, (in my case here I am just taking an example) is this the best way to explicitly register the bean.

Comment: And I answered to that. The best way is to annotate the class with `@Component` or to use a `@Bean` annotated method in a Configuration class. You would use a `@Bean` annotated method when you can't modify the class and add an annotation, or when the object must be created and configured, and not just instantiated with a constructor.